# Re-establishing Gmail’s Old Interface?

Tags: gmail

A few weeks ago, my Gmail layout changed from a "uniform" layout where all emails were shown according to the newest (by date and time), to one where emails are now grouped under three tabs under the headings of **Primary**, **Social** and **Promotions** as depicted below:

[image]

Is it possible to revert back to the old style layout, without my emails being grouped under these three tabs?

Comment: Unless this is a change that has not be rolled out to everyone you should be able to just click `Inbox`.  You can disable all the tabs also by doing `Configure Inbox`

Comment: If you click the `+` on the right of the tabs, and uncheck all the tabs you can, the inbox should revert to how you remember it.

Comment: @AlEverett - He still has to go into Settings->Inbox and change the `Inbox Type`

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm not so sure about that, based on my own experimentation.

Comment: @Simon This article maybe of assistance http://www.howtogeek.com/171628/forget-the-gimmicks-heres-the-best-way-to-organize-your-gmail-inbox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the solution after I enabled this myself while attempting to post a comment solution.

[Settings->Inbox](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm#settings/inbox)

[image: Settings->Inbox]

The tab interface can be enabled accidently by Configure Inbox:

[image: Configure Inbox]

Comment: If you enable tabs through Configure Inbox change the inbox type to default.

Comment: Thanks also for migrating from SuperUser. I had forgotten there was a Web Apps SE

Answer (score 2):

1. Hover over *Inbox*
2. Click on the right-side arrow that appears
3. Choose anything **but** *Default*

[image]

Comment: This is the quick shortcut to the solution.  Both answers results in the same result.

Comment: @Alex Appreciate your alternative answer